# Axis2: What's the difference between Modules and Services?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

What is the difference between Modules and Services in web-services ( AXIS2.x )?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Axis2, a **service** is a Web Service. Quoting the [W3C definition of a web service](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-ws-gloss-20040211/#webservice):

> A Web service is a software system
>   designed to support interoperable
>   machine-to-machine interaction over a
>   network. It has an interface described
>   in a machine-processable format
>   (specifically WSDL). Other systems
>   interact with the Web service in a
>   manner prescribed by its description
>   using SOAP-messages, typically
>   conveyed using HTTP with an XML
>   serialization in conjunction with
>   other Web-related standards.

**[Axis2 Modules](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/modules/index.html)** are extensions for Axis2 which provide additional functionality for Axis2 services, including implementations of some of the [WS-* standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications).

Comment: So 
   Axis - Services are those WSDLS developed and ready for usage ...for deployment
   axis - Modules are those existing POJOS ( top- down / bottom -top ) hosted for creation of  WSDLS .... AM i correct or Please give an simple example ???

Comment: No, I think you misunderstand. A service is a piece of functionality that you can invoke by sending a message and waiting for a response. WSDL is the schema used to describe the service in an industry-standard format. Axis2 is a Java framework for creating services. And Axis2 Modules are extensions for Axis2 to bolt-on additional functionality, for this like addressing and security.